# How to set flexible width buttons in a view in iOS 8 using Autolayout?

Tags: objective-c, button, ios8, ios-autolayout

I have a UIView with 2 button. Each of them are place left and right of the view. I need to set constraints to the button with flexible width only with a horizontal spacing between these 2 buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting up your left button:

1. Align your button to the left, add a Leading Space constraint.
2. Align your button vertically.

Setting your right button:

1. Align your button to the right, add a Trailing Space constraint.
2. Align your button vertically.

Connecting the buttons:

1. Select your left button
2. Connect your button with the right button with CTRL+drag to it and select horizontal spacing.
3. Connect your buttons again, but select Equal Widths

Finalize your settings

1. Select the Horizontal spacing constraint and set the distance between the buttons, for example: 8.
2. Select your buttons and use Selected Views/Update Frames from the right bottom corner of the UI Editor.

Here is a screenshot with the constraints:

[image: Screenshot with the constraints]